# Exception due to unknown party when initiating flow [errorCode=1x4roxc]

Tags: corda

I am trying to `initiateFlow` but I am getting the error below.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Don't know about O=ALICE, L=London, C=GB
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowMessagingImpl.sendSessionMessage(FlowMessaging.kt:55) ~[classes/:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.ActionExecutorImpl.executeSendInitial(ActionExecutorImpl.kt:171) ~[classes/:?]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah. I had accidentally deleted my "additional-nodes" folder after bootstrapping.

This meant that my node was unaware of all other participants.

Rebootstrapping fixed the issue.